# Why does my footer div not move below another div?

Tags: css, html

I've looked at every similar question I can find here. I have a div for my right column, and then a div for my footer. But if my right column gets too long, it covers up the footer. What is wrong?

Site: http://www.powerhousestudios.tv/2013/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have `height: 410px` on the sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

On your DIV

```
<div id="rightcolumn">
```

CSS READS

```
#rightcolumn {
width: 300px;
float: right;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 410px;
```

Remove the Height Parameter to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `rightcolumn` div has a fixed height of `410px`, which it seems it's not enough. Just remove the `height` property.

Answer (score 0):

Your using relative positioning on the upcoming div. That with a z-index of 999 is making it cover your footer div.

Try:

```
upcoming { z-index: 0;}
```

and remove the spacing paragraphs in that div to get the effect you want.